# Rails render and pass query param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller-action

This is in the login action. I'm trying to adapt it to send back a return_url query param, and i'm failing with a simple render.

**Prior:**

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {
      flash.now[:error] = error
      render
    }
```

**Attempt 1:**

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {
      flash.now[:error] = error
      render return_url => "blah" 
    }
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {
      flash.now[:error] = error
      render "login", local =>  {return_url => "blah"}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I passed **params[:redirect_after_error]** after an error and that solved it.

```
  respond_to do |format|
            format.html {
                flash.now[:error] = error
                 params[:redirect_after_error]  = params[:return_url]
              render
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand. You are trying to pass a return_url to the view. Right?
So if you want that you can just create a instance variable that contains the value of the returning url
For ex

```
@return_url = root_path() #or change it to url you want
#Then follow with the code you written
#You will see that you can use @return_url in the view without doing anything else.
```

If it doesn't answer your question. Could you be precise. I am not so sure I do understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

for this view should have one instance variable when its render, so if its fail you just render to root_path

ex:

> @user = xxxx respond_to do |format|
>       if @user.save
>        format.html { redirect_to @users, notice: 'user was successfully created.' }
>     else
>         format.html { render root_path, :alert: error }
>       end
>    end